# Highcharts is not defined. Error log in console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, bower

Please help me. This error log in console in my angular app.

[image]

My App section:

```
angular.module('fbApp', [
        'ngSanitize',
        'ngRoute',
        'ui.bootstrap',     
        'ui.router',         
        'ui.utils',
        'chieffancypants.loadingBar',
        'ui.date',
        'angular-underscore',
        'highcharts-ng'
    ])
```

My index.html from bower:

```
<!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/highcharts-ng/dist/highcharts-ng.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/src/loading-bar.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-underscore/angular-underscore.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: It doesn't look like you have the highcharts script.  You just have the directives.

Comment: Apart of highcharts-ng.js, you need to load highcharts.js library.

Answer (score 9):

highcharts-ng depends on hightcharts so you need to install them both.

```
bower install --save highcharts
bower install --save highcharts-ng
```

Answer (score 4):

I've come across exactly same problem. I think the answer is in the documentation. Check the git hub documentation [Git hub documentation](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng?utm_source=angular-js.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation)
I found the solution to this. Insert the below script tag in the index above the script tag highcharts-ng.js

`<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/highcharts-ng/src/highcharts-ng.js"></script>`

This should remove the error.

Comment: More exactly the bower one and `<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/4.2.2/highstock.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

Download highcharts.js and link it in your app. You only have the angular directive `highcharts-ng` .

Comment: Had the same problem this worked for me, add: <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this via bower.json; Update the following dependencies.

```
"highcharts" : "*",
"highcharts-ng" : "*"
```

[image]

Run the `bower update` from the command line project directory.

Use the "highcharts-ng module

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',
[
    "highcharts-ng",
    "ngRoute",
    "myApp.view1",
    "myApp.view2",
    "myApp.version"
]);
```

Include the following in the index.html or view

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/highcharts-ng/dist/highcharts-ng.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like highcharts.js is dependent on jQuery. Verify that jQuery is loading correctly and it's the correct version.

Comment: Jquery load is correctly https://www.dropbox.com/s/ngmc0szcwoovaoc/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-05-28%2001.33.15.png